# How do I create an OpenCV image from the contents of a file?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Usually I would create an image in OpenCV as:

```
from cv2 import imread
img = imread("/home/nick/myfile.jpg")
```

But already have the contents of the file in another variable, so how to I create an OpenCV from this directly? e.g.

```
fc = open("/home/nick/myfile.jpg", "rb").read()
img = something(fc)
```

What is `something`? Is there an OpenCV or numpy function to do this?

Answer (score 0):

cv2.imdecode() can do that in memory. and yes, it wants a numpy array as input

Comment: I guess the question is then how do I convert `fc` into a numpy array?